# DBT Cloud: downstream models not building

Tags: dbt

I have a dbt cloud project that has `erp_distributor_selected.sql` as its first model. There are downstream models e.g. `erp_sel_flatfile_transaction_references2.sql`.

When I run

```
dbt run --models +erp_distributor_selected+
```

the same model doesnt run (waited for hours). Please see image: [image]

However, The strange part is that when I run

```
dbt run --models erp_sel_flatfile_transaction_references2
```

the model builds in a few seconds! Please see image: [image]

Anyone else who's faced a similar issue, any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: The first thing I can think of - are you using dbt's `{{ ref() }}` syntax (https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/ref/) in your `erp_sel_flatfile_transaction_references2` model to reference the `erp_distributor_selected` model? Otherwise the downstream dependency will not be created.

Answer (score 1):

As @BrandenCiranni mentioned, you should make sure that you are using the ref() function to reference the other models. This is how dbt figures out the order of how it needs to run models. If you are already using ref() function throughout your code, please post your sql/dbt_project.yml for more context.